# Header and nav menu problem on Thesis site

Tags: menus, theme-thesis, custom-header

Unfortunately I managed to make the header image disappear and the horizontal nav menu distort on this Thesis themed Wordpress site I'm helping a friend with

[www.euanmitchell.com.au](http://euanmitchell.com.au)

I've pasted the code from Thesis custom.css and custom-functions.php below. Any help is much appreciated.

Cheers,

Les

```
    File: custom.css
Description: Custom styles for Thesis
More Info: http://diythemes.com/thesis/rtfm/custom-css/
*/

#header {
border: none;
background-image: url(http://euanmitchell.com.au/wp-conten...bannerv6.jpg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
height: 208px;
padding: 0;
position: relative;
}

.custom #header #logo a {
text-indent: -9999px;
width: 450px;
height: 169px;
display: block;
float: left;
}

.custom .teaser {
width: 100%;
margin-top: 2em;
padding-top: 2em;
border-top: 1px dotted #bbb;
text-align: justify;
}
.custom .teasers_box {
padding-top: 0;
padding-bottom:0;
border-top: 0;
}

.custom #header { height:150px; background:transparent url(images/header.png) center no-repeat; } 



 <?php
/* ---:[ place your custom code below this line ]:---*/

remove_action('thesis_hook_before_header', 'thesis_nav_menu');
add_action('thesis_hook_after_header', 'thesis_nav_menu');
remove_action('thesis_hook_footer', 'thesis_attribution');

?>
```

Comment: Les - If you're a registered user of Thesis, you may want to ask these questions on the Thesis forum http://diythemes.com/forums . Kiril Fuchs was able to come up with a great answer quickly, but in many cases theme and plugin specific questions are normally closed before you can get an answer.

Answer (score 0):

**The nav bar:**

Your float:left; property in:

```
.custom #header #logo a { text-indent: -9999px; width: 450px; height: 169px; display: block; **float: left;** }
```

is causing the nav bar to act all funny. You have 2 options:

1. get rid of the float left.
2. clear your float left after the logo.

**IE:** add `clear:left; or clear:both;` to your `.menu-custom-container`

**The Image:**

It seems its unable to find header.png in

wp-content/themes/thesis_184/custom/images/header.png

Also it looks like you have uploaded the header image into the theme.

could this be it? http://euanmitchell.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/euanbannerv6.jpg

if that's the case you can completely get rid of the background-image and split the remaining properties into individual properties since #header contains this code:

```
background-image: url(http://euanmitchell.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/euanbannerv6.jpg);
```

so your new css would be:

```
.custom #header { height:150px; background-color:transparent; background-position: center; background-repeat:no-repeat; }
```

That will take care of the image not showing up.

**Edit:**

Also you don't need the no-repeat because it also in the #header or the transparent color because it's white anyway. TBH they don't add anything, the only real property your adding is background-position:center;.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Kirill Fuchs. The menu problem is now resolved, but the header is still not showing. I've tried reloading the header image with no success.

Comment: Yes sorry, the css was still overwritting the background-image property from #header. Just split the remaining properties. I edited my answer and should be correct now. Let me know how it turns out. Also you don't need the no-repeat or the color tbh, the only real property your adding is background-position:center;

Comment: Thanks again for your help. The header image is now visible, but it's not fitting as it should. Attempts to tweak the height and width don't seem to be doing much. Sorry to be such a newb. http://euanmitchell.com.au/

Comment: @LesThomas I took another look and it seems like you've got it working. Or did I not understand the new problem?

Comment: Sorry Kirill Fuch, I added height 300px to .custom #header last thing before sleep and that made all of the image visible on my screen. I'm not sure that it's perfect, so I'll check it out on other screens today. Big thanks!

Comment: okay sounds good and glad I could help.